# Conteúdo do arquivo não é lido por completo

Tags: totalcross

Estou com um caso em que o conteúdo do arquivo não é lido inteiro, apenas parte dele. Segue o exemplo:

Realizei o teste para ver se o arquivo estava correto no dispositivo abrindo ele sem utilizar o totalcross e o arquivo encontra-se completo.

Caso necessite de uma cópia do arquivo eu encaminho por e-mail. O mesmo possui: 20k.

```
public class DSINTesteMainWindow extends MainWindow {

public DSINTesteMainWindow()
{
    super("Teste", Window.NO_BORDER);

    Convert.setDefaultConverter("UTF8");
}

public void initUI()
{

    try {
        Vm.debug(new String(new File("/sdcard/dsin/20170526143838985", File.READ_ONLY).readAndClose()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

Comment: por favor, me envia esse arquivo por email. Vou ver aqui algumas alternativas para contornar essa questão enquanto isso

Comment: Descobri o que está acontecendo: o método `File.read` não é bloqueante, assim como os demais métodos que dependem dele: `readAndClose()` e `readAndDelete()`. Isso significa que leituras grandes podem não ser realizadas em uma única passada. Esses métodos serão depreciados. Estou postando uma alternativa mais consistente na resposta